# Getting all of the .json files from a directory

Tags: javascript, php, android, json

I'm creating an android app which takes in some json data, is there a way to set up a directory such as;

```
http://......./jsons/*.json
```

Alternatively, a way to add into a json file called a.json, and extend its number of containing array data, pretty much add more data into the .json file this increase its size.
It could be by PHP or Javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up a directory"? Where you going to "setup"? on your server?

Comment: That info would help... on the online server. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Parsing JSON, you can use the JSON.parse() function, in addition, I'm not sure about getting all your JSON files from a directory call, maybe someone else will explain that.

```
var data ='{"name":"Ray Wlison",
            "position":"Staff Author",
            "courses":[
              "JavaScript & Ajax",
              "Buildinf Facebook Apps"]}';
var info = JSON.parse(data);
//var infostoring = JSON.stringify(info);
```

Comment: Still curious about getting all of the .json files from an online server directory :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to add to a json file is to parse it, add to it, then save it again. This might not be optimal if you have large amounts of data but in that case you'll probably want a proper database anyway (like mongo).

Using PHP:

```
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('a.json'));
array_push($json_data, 'some value');
file_put_contents('a.json', json_encode($json_data));
```